# What are some examples of quaternions in rectangular and exponential form?

Tags: quaternions

I've been interested in quaternions for their ability to represent positions and motions in spacetime in application to game development; I have searched for articles regarding representations of quaternions online for a few days, and a bit of it helped, but my knowledge of higher mathematics is limited and I struggled to make sense of many of the equations shown in these articles. I realize the study of quaternions is a deep subject closely linked with trigonometry and linear algebra, but at the moment my only interest is in the polar/exponential representation of quaternions.

During my search for information on this notion, I found an article that illustrated a particular form of expressing quaternions,
'[Quaternion polar representation with a complex modulus and
complex argument inspired by the Cayley-Dickson form](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.0852.pdf)' by Stephen J. Sangwine and Nicolas Le Bihan

In the introduction of this document, it says any quaternion of the form $q = a+b\hat i+c\hat j+d\hat k$ may be expressed as $q = |q|e^{\hat i\phi}e^{\hat k\psi}e^{\hat j\theta}$.

This article, '[Hypercomplex Signals—A Novel Extension of the
Analytic Signal to the Multidimensional Case](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/inf/Sommer/doc/Publications/tbl/buelow01tsp.pdf)' by Thomas Bülow and Gerald Sommer, states the same idea in part five of the document.

I've read through these articles and others, taking what I can from them with my current insight on trigonometry, but I have yet to grasp how to correctly convert a quaternion from rectangular form $a+b\hat i+c\hat j+d\hat k$ to the portrayed exponential form $|q|e^{\hat i\phi}e^{\hat k\psi}e^{\hat j\theta}$. I feel that seeing some examples of quaternions in both forms would help me understand the conversion.

Thus, given that $q = a+b\hat i+c\hat j+d\hat k = |q|e^{\hat i\phi}e^{\hat k\psi}e^{\hat j\theta}$, what would the following quaternions be in the form $|q|e^{\hat i\phi}e^{\hat k\psi}e^{\hat j\theta}$?

- $3+4\hat i+2\hat j+3\hat k$
- $3\hat i+4\hat j$
- $5\hat i+3\hat j+\hat k$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi$, $\psi$ and $\theta$ are just Euler angles you can easily convert back and forth from quaternions to Euler angles following the formulae showed in wikipedia:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles